# How to clear drawrect in Ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawrect

I came up with a scenario like drawing a line graph using DrawRect method. Using the same code i should plot three more types of line graphs. How should i clear already plotted graph and draw another...Posting one of the clasess drawRect method. Please look at it and suggest me a solution for this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect 
{
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
     CGContextClearRect(context, self.bounds);
     CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, true);

    CGRect currentBounds = self.bounds;
    CGFloat dotsWidth = self.numberOfPages*kDotDiameter + MAX(0,     self.numberOfPages-1)*kDotSpacer;
    CGFloat x = CGRectGetMidX(currentBounds)-dotsWidth/2;
    CGFloat y = CGRectGetMidY(currentBounds)-kDotDiameter/2;
    for (int i=0; i<_numberOfPages; i++)
    {
        CGRect circleRect = CGRectMake(x, y, kDotDiameter, kDotDiameter);
        if (i == _currentPage)
        {
            CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor);
        }
       else
       {
           CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor);
       }
        CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, circleRect);
        x += kDotDiameter + kDotSpacer;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following, rect should be containing the line graph bounds.

```
CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect);
```

Comment: CGContextClearRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), rect); didnt work

Comment: Did you use it in drawRect method? Please share your code.

Comment: There are several places where i'm using drawrect method.Every where i used CGContextClearRect method...

Comment: I'm developing a app..In that i need to show report analysis(Daily,monthly,weekly,yearly). For that i used some sample code to plot Line graph. For fetching the data i'm using PHP Api. Using that api i'm plotting the graph. So my acctual code (calling api and displaying content of plotted thing is in one class) and those draw rect methods are in sample code(classess).I createad an instance to call those sample code classess in my main class. Hope you understood what i'm trying to say

Comment: You can add a Bool flag for clearing in sample classes, if you need clearing, which means flag is true, you add the above code, if not,you draw the Line graph. You should do the clearance where you do the drawing. Suppose you draw the Line graph in View A,then you should clear the rect in View A's drawRect method.